# In Production :: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds) (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting the error

> /home/yaswant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:189:in
>   `block in wait_poll': could not obtain a database connection within
>   5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds) (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError)

my connection pool has 30 connection.
my app is api based application where I am using threads out side the rails .
Please suggest how I can resolve this

Comment: It's difficult to help without knowing more. What have you tried? How are you connecting? Can you connect from a terminal?

Comment: Make responses faster? Make less db requests? There is no simple answer. But if you have 30 connection pool on localhost and manage to kill the API I smell there's something wrong with your design.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel i am facing this error in prod environment.

Comment: Then I guess you should learn how to load balance the requests. Just increasing the limit on the db will run you into a wall in the long term. As I said it's also good to make sure all API responses are as fast as possible if you work under high load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the pool of connections that your application will use.

Sidekiq will take 25 per queue by default, which means if you have a pool of 10, then you will end up having alot of errors showing, they will eventually succeed but it will take much longer to do so.